# How to implement UISearchBar to filter name or capital JSON using JSON Decoder in swift iOS application

Tags: ios, json, swift, uisearchbar, searchbar

How to implement UISearchBar to filter name or capital JSON using JSON Decoder in swift iOS application. I want to implement UISearchBar and search results or filter results using name from JSON Data.

```
  import UIKit
```

Structure Created

```
  struct jsonstruct:Decodable
  {
  let name:String   
   let capital:String
  }

  class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
```

Creating Outlet for TableView and SearchBar

```
   @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

   @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Declaring JSON

```
   var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
```

Function for getting Data

```
func getdata()
{
let url = URL(string: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!)
{
(data, response, error) in

do
{
if error == nil
{
self.arrdata = try
JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct].self, from: data!)

for mainarr in self.arrdata
{
print(mainarr.name,":",mainarr.capital as Any)
DispatchQueue.main.async 
{
self.tableview.reloadData()
}
}
}
}
catch
{
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
}.resume()
}
```

TABLE VIEW

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
return self.arrdata.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
cell.label1.text = "Name: \(arrdata[indexPath.row].name)"
cell.label2.text = "Capital: \(arrdata[indexPath.row].capital)"
return cell
}
```

OverRiding Function

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
getdata()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two objects of data, one original data and other filtered data.

```
var filteredArrData = [jsonstruct]()
var arrdata = [jsonstruct]()
```

Than in your getData functions:

```
do {
 self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct].self, from: data!)
 self.filteredArrData = self.arrdata
}
```

Then in your table view delegate and data source:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
   return self.filteredArrData.count
}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
   cell.label1.text = "Name: \(filteredArrData[indexPath.row].name)"
   cell.label2.text = "Capital: \(filteredArrData[indexPath.row].capital)"
   return cell
}
```

Than make filter function like this:

```
func applyFilters(textSearched: String) {
            filteredArrData = arrdata.filter({ item -> Bool in
            return item.name.lowercased().hasPrefix(textSearched.lowercased())
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Then pass your string to this function and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make TextField with an IBAction of didbegin like below and create an array where you can have filtered data.

```
@IBAction func tfSearch(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let filteredArray = yourArr.filter { $0.contains(sender.text) }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not caching all your data and the filtering is done live via an API. You will need to set an object or the viewcontroller as a delegate of the search bar(UISearchBarDelegate). Then use the searchText as the text for your API query.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    //call throttle that will call urlsession
}
```

Since one character is typed at a time we do not to call the API every time. You may need to use a throttler to make lesser API calls instead of sending character by character search. You might find this tutorial about throttling helpful: [Simple Throttling in Swift](https://www.craftappco.com/blog/2018/5/30/simple-throttling-in-swift) .

Most REST APIs should have a filter feature and you could just easily append the typed name or capital.

```
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/append name here
https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/capital/append capital here
```

This is an example networking code to fetch the results. Use the results to call another method safely on the main queue to reload the tableview.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/country?q=name") {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
          do {
             let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourCustomDecodeStruct.self, from: data)
             //safely your data source and reload the tableview
          } catch let error {
             print(error)
          }
       }
   }.resume()
}
```